# need to load a webview programmatically with custom width & height on windows phone app 7/8/8.1/10

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I am new to windows phone app development. I need to know is there any way to load a webview on windows 7/8/8.1/10 after making an http request to a server and using the parameters returned from server as height and width. Also i would like to know how to assign an id to layout in case there are multiple webviews and assign width and height to them individually.

Comment: Yes you can add webview programmatically after getting response from Http request.

Comment: Can u give me a sample code to begin with ?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
WebView webView=new WebView();
webView.Navigate("Url where you want to navigate");
webView.Height= //set the height;
webView.Width=  //set the Width;
```

and after this add this webview to parent.Suppose parent is Grid then :

```
grid.Children.Add(webView);
```

Also you can assign Id to multiple web views like this :

```
WebView webView=new WebView(){Name="WebView1"};
WebView webView=new WebView(){Name="WebView2"};
```

Hope it will help you :)